# Python. Reversing list from sys.argv

Tags: python

I need to reverse the words, which inputes with launching the program.
Example:

```
$ python1.py ['force', 'the', 'Feel']
```

I need to get: Feel the force

I've tried that code:

```
import sys
n = (sys.argv[1:])
print ' '.join(n[::-1])
```

But it doesn't work as I hoped. It saves all commas, etc

Comment: how about just running: python1.py 'force'  'the'  'Feel'

Comment: There is exact task. There are different input variants: strings, integers, list. So the programm should work with each one.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $ python1.py ['force', 'the', 'Feel']
> ```
>
> I need to get: Feel the force

```
from sys import argv
from ast import literal_eval
list_ = literal_eval(' '.join(argv[1:]))
print ' '.join(reversed(list_))
```

Comment: Thanks. But there's also tasks with non list strings. My fault that I didnt notice that. In your variant everything works fine if list is input. But when I need to enter a string or an integer - doesn't work.